# Is it possible to make many M:N join tables between two tables? (Seqeulize, MySQL)

Tags: sequelize.js

I have two tables: meeting and user.

I'd like to show both likes and favorites between these two tables.

My plan is to declare and use two join tables that are created by connecting the meeting and user tables with M:N.

I want to know if that is syntactically possible in Sequelize.

The sample code that I'd like to create is below.

```
db.Meeting.belongsToMany(db.User, {
            as : 'Like',
            through: 'Likes',
            foreignKey: 'gathering_idx',
            otherKey: 'user_idx',
            timestamps: false 
        });
db.Meeting.belongsToMany(db.User, {
            as : 'Favorite',
            through: 'Favorites',
            foreignKey: 'gathering_idx',
            otherKey: 'user_idx',
            timestamps: false 
        });
```

Also, If I define a relationship like the code above, can I use relationship query functions like addLike, setLike, addFavorite, and set Favorite in Sequelize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use two different tables to link `Meeting` and `User` it's all good.

And of course feel free to use special methods to work with relationship records.

Linking existing meetings and users is simply about adding records to `Likes` or to `Favorites` as you know many-to-many tables are what for.